# how to get the all subset of a set python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to define a number like 3 then make it a set

```
x = set(range(1,n+1))
```

and then show all subset of this set :

```
{}
{1}
{1, 2}
{1, 2, 3}
{1, 3}
{2}
{2, 3}
{3}
```

Comment: I cant use any library for this just loops

Comment: @mujad then specify your recent comment it in the question as it's a condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_result(x):
    len_x = len(x)
    res = []
    for i in range(0, 2**(len_x)):
        res.append(take(x, i))
    print("count:{}".format(len(res)))
    return res

def take(x, i):
    res = set()
    idx = 1
    while i:
        if i & 1:
            res.add(idx)
        idx += 1
        i >>= 1
    return res

print(get_result({1, 2, 3}))
print(get_result({1, 2, 3, 4}))
```

Are you looking for some simple solutions like above?

Comment: yes ! but this don't return {}